# $S_1$: compact, $S_2$: any topological space. Then $S_1\times S_2\ni (x,y)\mapsto y\in S_2$ is a closed mapping.

Tags: general-topology, closed-map

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Definition:
> Let $(S,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> Let $x\in S$.
> Let $V\subset S$.
> If $x$ is an interior point of $V$, then $V$ is called a neighborhood of $x$.

> Definition:
> Let $(S,\mathcal{O})$ be a topological space.
> Let $x\in S$.
> $\mathbf{V}_S(x)$ is the set of all neighborhoods of $x$.

> Problem 5 on p.223:
> Let $S_1$ be a compact topological space.
> Let $S_2$ be a topological space.
> Let $\mathrm{pr}_2$ be a mapping from $S_1\times S_2$ to $S_2$ such that $\mathrm{pr}_2((x,y))=y$.
> Prove that  $\mathrm{pr}_2$ is a closed mapping.

> The author's answer:
> Let $A$ be a closed set in $S_1\times S_2$.
> Let $B:=\mathrm{pr}_2(A)$.
> We show that $S_2-B$ is an open set in $S_2$.
> Let $y\in S_2-B$.
> Then, $(x,y)\notin A$ for any $x\in S_1$.
> Since $A$ is closed, there exist $U_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_1}(x)$ and $V_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_2}(y)$ such that $(U_x\times V_x)\cap A=\emptyset$.
> We can assume that $U_x$ is an open set in $S_1$.
> Then, $\{U_x\mid x\in S_1\}$ is an open covering of $S_1$.
> Since $S_1$ is compact, there exist $x_1,\dots,x_r\in S_1$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{r} U_{x_i}=S_1$.
> Let $V:=\bigcap_{i=1}^{r} V_{x_i}$.
> Then, $V\in\mathbf{V}_{S_2}(y)$ and obviously $(S_1\times V)\cap A=\emptyset$.
> So, $V\cap B=\emptyset$ and $V\subset S_2-B$.
> So, $S_2-B$ is an open set in $S_2$.

The author wrote as follows:

> Since $A$ is closed, there exist $U_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_1}(x)$ and $V_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_2}(y)$ such that $(U_x\times V_x)\cap A=\emptyset$.

I know the following:

> Since $S_1\times S_2-A$ is open, there exist an open set $U_x$ and an open set $V_x$ such that $(x,y)\in U_x\times V_x\subset S_1\times S_2-A$.

The open set $U$ which contains $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$.
So, the author is not wrong.
But why did the author write "there exist $U_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_1}(x)$ and $V_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_2}(y)$"?

My answer is the following:

> My answer:
> Let $A$ be a closed set in $S_1\times S_2$.
> Let $B:=\mathrm{pr}_2(A)$.
> We show that $S_2-B$ is an open set in $S_2$.
> Let $y\in S_2-B$.
> Then, $(x,y)\notin A$ for any $x\in S_1$.
> Since $S_1\times S_2-A$ is open, there exist an open set $U_x$ and an open set $V_x$ such that $(x,y)\in U_x\times V_x\subset S_1\times S_2-A$.
> Then, $\{U_x\mid x\in S_1\}$ is an open covering of $S_1$.
> Since $S_1$ is compact, there exist $x_1,\dots,x_r\in S_1$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{r} U_{x_i}=S_1$.
> Let $V:=\bigcap_{i=1}^{r} V_{x_i}$.
> Then, $y\in V$ and obviously $S_1\times V\subset S_1\times S_2-A$.
> So, $V\subset S_2-B$.
> So, $S_2-B$ is an open set in $S_2$.

Comment: Aren't you saying the same thing?

Comment: An open set which contains $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. But a neighborhood of $x$ is not an open set in general.

Comment: Bold $V$ there maybe stands for open nbd.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author wants to say: since $A=\overline A$ and $x\not\in A,$ $\exists$ $U_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_1}(x)$ and $V_x\in\mathbf{V}_{S_2}(y)$ such that $(U_x\times V_x)\cap A=\emptyset$. Note you are using that since $x$ is not in the closure of A, exists a open base set $U_x\times V_x\subset S_1\times S_2$ which is neighbourhood of x which does not intersect $A=\overline A$. Your prove is also correct, to be more precise you can specify you are using the property that an open set is a neighborhood of all his points and conclude that you can find $\forall x\not \in A ,(U_x\times V_x)\subset S_1\times S_2\setminus A $ because $S_1\times S_2\setminus A$ is open since A is closed.

Comment: giorgiokyn23, Thank you very much for your answer.